# How to prove: $\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{4-3\sqrt[4]{5}+2\sqrt[4]{25}-\sqrt[4]{125}}}-1\right)^{4}=5$?

Tags: calculus, arithmetic, radicals

**Question:**

> show that: the beautiful ${\tt sqrt}$-identity:
>
> $$
> \left({2 \over \sqrt{\vphantom{\Large A}\, 4\ -\ 3\,\sqrt[4]{\,5\,}\
> +\ 2\,\sqrt[4]{\,25\,}\ - \,\sqrt[4]{\,125\,}\,}\,}\ -\ 1\right)^{4}
> =5
> $$

Can you someone have methods to prove this by hand? (Maybe this problem have many methods?because this result is integer. It's a surprise to me.)
Thank you

Because I found this
$$4\ -\ 3\sqrt[4]{\,5\,}\ +\ 2\sqrt[4]{\,25\,}\ -\ \sqrt[4]{\,125\,}$$ is not square numbers.

Comment: Have I made a typo, or does this actually evaluate to 5? [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%2Fsqrt%284-3*5%5E0.25%2B2*25%5E0.25-125%5E0.25%29+-+1%29%5E4)

Comment: Isn't $5$ for the rhs ?

Comment: Isn't $5$ for the rhs ?

Comment: Yes,sorry,the right is integer $5$.

Comment: Beautiful? I guess it is in the eye of the beholder :-)

Comment: What does "sqrt" mean?

Comment: "sqrt" is short for square-root.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hint: Set $x=5^{1/4}$, then
$$
\frac{2}{\sqrt{4-3x+2x^2-x^3}}-1=x
$$
This equation simplifies to 
$$
x(x^4-5)=0
$$
The rest is clear.

Comment: The *equation simplifies to* part is a little obscure.

Comment: @barakmanos $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{4-3x+2x^2-x^3}}-1=x\implies 2=(x+1)\sqrt{4-3x+2x^2-x^3}\implies (4-3x+2x^2-x^3)(x+1)^2=4\implies x(x^4-5)=0$$

Answer (score 6):

Let $x = 4-3\sqrt[4]{5}+2\sqrt[4]{25}-\sqrt[4]{125}$. Then, we have:

(1) $x = 4 - 3 \cdot 5^{1/4} + 2 \cdot 5^{2/4} - 5^{3/4}$

(2) $5^{1/4}x = 4\cdot 5^{1/4} - 3 \cdot 5^{2/4} + 2 \cdot 5^{3/4} - 5$ (Multiply (1) by $5^{1/4}$)

(3) $(5^{1/4}+1)x = -1 + 5^{1/4} - 5^{2/4} +5^{3/4}$ (Add (1) and (2))

(4) $5^{1/4}(5^{1/4}+1)x = -5^{1/4} + 5^{2/4} - 5^{3/4} +5$ (Multiply (3) by $5^{1/4}$)

(5) $(5^{1/4}+1)^2x = 4$ (Add (3) and (4))

Therefore, $x = \dfrac{4}{(5^{1/4}+1)^2}$. Hence, $\left(\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{x}}-1\right)^4 = \left(\dfrac{2}{\tfrac{2}{5^{1/4}+1}}-1\right)^4 = (5^{1/4}+1-1)^4 = 5$.

Answer (score 3):

[This is a paraphrase on JimmyK4542's elegant answer earlier]

Let $$b=-5^{\frac 14}$$

Then the long expression under the long square root sign becomes an arithmetico-geometric series:
$$k=4+3b+2b^2+b^3$$
Multiplying by $b$:
$$\begin{align}
b\cdot k&=\quad \qquad 4b+3b^2+2b^3+b^4\\
&=\quad \qquad 4b+3b^2+2b^3+5 \end{align}$$
Subtracting:
$$\begin{align}
(b-1)k&=1+b+b^2+b^3\\
&=\dfrac{b^4-1}{b-1}\\
&=\dfrac 4{b-1}\\
k&=\dfrac 4{(b-1)^2}\\
\sqrt{k}&=\dfrac 2{1-b}\\
\left( \dfrac 2{\sqrt{k}} -1\right)^4&={(-b)}^4=5
\end{align}$$